# How can I solve "lex program for the pattern that starts with vowel, ends with consonant and might have digits too"

Tags: lex

I have tried to solve this question "Write a lex program for the pattern that starts with vowel, ends with consonant and might have digits too."

Here is my code:

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int cno=0, wno=0, lno=o;
%}

character [a-zA-z]
digit [0-9]
word({character}|{digit})+
line\n
%%
{line}{cno++;lno++;}
{line}{wno++; cno+=strlen(yytext);}{cno++;}
%%

int main(void)
{
    yylex();
    print("Count alphanumeric pattern: %d;", cno);
    print("Length of string: %d;", wno);
    print("Line numbers: %d\n", lno);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
line 23: unrecognized rule
line 23: fatal parse error
```

Comment: There must be at least one whitespace character between name and definition in the definition section and between pattern and action in the rule section. Please review the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Format.html#Format). You will also find the complete pattern syntax, in the next section in the same manual.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code will solve your problem.

```
%{
int valid_patterns = 0, invalid_patterns =0;
%}

PATTERN ([aeiouAEIOU][A-Za-z0-9]*[b-df-hj-np-tv-zB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z])*


%%
{PATTERN} {printf("\n\t Pattern Matched: %s", yytext); valid_patterns++;}
[A-Za-z0-9]+ {invalid_patterns++;}
"\n" {
    printf("\n\n\t Total Matched Patterns  : %d", valid_patterns);
    printf("\n\t Total Unmatched Patterns: %d\n", invalid_patterns);
    valid_patterns = 0; invalid_patterns = 0;
}
%%


/*** User code section***/

int yywrap(){}

int main(int argc, char **argv[])
{
    printf("\n Enter your inputs: \n\n");
    yylex();

    return 0;
}
```

Explanation of the first rule for PATTERN as per your questions requirements:

- `[aeiouAEIOU]` make sure a pattern starts with a vowel.
- `[A-Za-z0-9]*` indicates that any alphanumeric character can occur in middle.
- `[b-df-hj-np-tv-zB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]` make sure a pattern ends with a consonant.
- `(...)*` indicates there might be 0 or more occurrence of desire pattern.

The second rule `[A-Za-z0-9]+` catches any other input that doesn't match the requirements. And the final rule `"\n"`takes action when you input a new line, it prints information about your inputs.

An I/O example---

Input: `Hello amazing people around the world`

Output:

```
 Pattern Matched: amazing
 Pattern Matched: around

 Total Matched Patterns  : 2
 Total Unmatched Patterns: 4
```